# Troubles with linking Rust lib when compiling as shared lib for Android using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, linker-errors, rust-cargo

No link errors when building as executable main.rs rather than lib.rs

**Error:**
linking with C:/Users/nafan/AppData/Local/ndk/26.2.11394342/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android34-clang++.cmd failed: exit code: 255

note: --version-script=C:\Users\nafan\AppData\Local\Temp\rustcfcjtoe\list"" was unexpected at this time.

**config.toml**

```ini
[target.aarch64-linux-android]
ar = "C:/Users/nafan/AppData/Local/ndk/26.2.11394342/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android34-clang++"
linker = "C:/Users/nafan/AppData/Local/ndk/26.2.11394342/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android34-clang++.cmd"
```

**Cargo.toml**

```ini
[lib]
name = "renderer"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
jni = "0.21.1"
```

**lib.rs**

```rust
use jni::{objects::JClass, sys::jint, JNIEnv};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn Java_com_example_myapp_RustInterface_rustFunction(_env: JNIEnv, _class: JClass) -> jint {
    let value = 42; // Example value

    // Convert the value to JNI jint and return it
    value as jint
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround is to change aarch64-linux-android34-clang++.cmd content a little bit

https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1856#issuecomment-1542248775